# async in OnGet will not wait the functions end and will go to the razor file?

Tags: asp.net-core

asp.net core web 3.1 in a **DownloadOrder.cshtml.cs** there is a `async` `OnGet` function.

```
public async void OnGet(int? pageIndex)
    {
        var list = GetProductList(pageIndex);

        PaginatedList = await PaginatedList<Models.OrderProduct>.CreateAsync(list, PageIndex, 10);
    }
```

But sometimes it will not wait the `OnGet` function and will go to the **DownloadOrder.cshtml** razor file.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PaginatedList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.OrderID</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductID</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

there will be an exception that The `Model.PaginatedList` is null.
it seems that the `await` is not waiting and will go to **razor html** first then go to the `await` function.

Comment: Can you show how do you call OnGet? Also, you should declare it as async Task instead of async void https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Comment: I think that it is calling a different method where PaginatedList is not being hydrated. place breakpoints on the other methods to see which is being called then add the code to populate the Paginated List in that method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know why. It should be `async Task OnGet` not `async void OnGet`

I do not know why.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Answer (score 3):

In short (from msdn):

> Async void methods have different composing semantics. Async methods returning Task or Task can be easily composed using await, Task.WhenAny, Task.WhenAll and so on. Async methods returning void don’t provide an easy way to notify the calling code that they’ve completed.

So your calling code will not know when your OnGet is done, and sometimes will execute before its completion, thus making your list object null.

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming