# Razor page rendering before OnGetAsync is evaluated

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, server-side-rendering, razor-pages

The code below return an `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')` error. The error is thrown by `Model.Players.Any()`. It seems the page is rendered before the code behind file is evaluated. I believe the error must related to the asyncronous call OnGetAsync, but I don't know how to fix it.
Using Visual Studio debugging I have checked the value of Players property and is evaluates correctly (but after the razor page has rendered - and thrown the error)

Code behind file(extract):

```
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public async void OnGetAsync()
    {
        IEnumerable<Club> clubs = await clubService.GetAllClubs();
        IEnumerable<User> users = _userManager.Users;

        Players = from user in users
                  join club in clubs on user.ClubId equals club.ClubId
                  orderby user.Name
                  select new Player
                  {
                      UserId = new Guid(user.Id),
                      Name = user.Name,
                      Surname = user.Surname,
                      DOB = user.DOB,
                      ClubId = club.ClubId,
                      ClubName = club.ClubName,
                      ClubLogo = club.ClubLogo
                  };
    }
```

Pazor page(extract):

```
    if (Model.Players.Any())
    {
        foreach (Player player in Model.Players.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ThenBy(u => u.Surname))
        {
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 my-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                        <h6>@player.Name @player.Surname</h6>
                        @if (player.ClubLogo != null)
                        {
                            <img src="~/img/clublogos/@player.ClubLogo" height="30" class="mx-2" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <h6>No players created yet</h6>
    }
```

Comment: `it seems the page is rendered before the code behind file is evaluated` No,the error message means Model.Players=null in your backend.You need to set breakpoint to debug the code and check the data.

Comment: This was what I did, and based on this I estabilished the order of rendering/evalutaion. 
That said, I think the true cause of the issue was the return type of the handlermethod. When OnGetAsync return type is void, it apparently doesn't wait the method the evaluate before rendering of the razor pages starts. When changing the return type to Task, this issue is fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async in OnGet will not wait the functions end and will go to the razor file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709222/async-in-onget-will-not-wait-the-functions-end-and-will-go-to-the-razor-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

The problem was the OnGetAsync handler method returning void instead of a Task

```
public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<Club> clubs = await clubService.GetAllClubs();
    IEnumerable<User> users = _userManager.Users;

    Players = from user in users
              join club in clubs on user.ClubId equals club.ClubId
              orderby user.Name
              select new Player
              {
                  UserId = new Guid(user.Id),
                  Name = user.Name,
                  Surname = user.Surname,
                  DOB = user.DOB,
                  ClubId = club.ClubId,
                  ClubName = club.ClubName,
                  ClubLogo = club.ClubLogo
              };
}
```